# Add the same string to all items in a list (or array) without use of loop or iterations

Tags: java

I have a list and would like to add the same string to all items in the list without for loops or iterations. So the modified list would have all its entries with the same additional string.

Is there a class or method available that does this in java

Thanks

Comment: How about a while loop? :D

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: also what version of java are you actually using?

Comment: You have a list of what - sample declaration of your list? How do you want to add, concatenation? Why don't you provide the code _with_ the loops, so we can better understand the intent.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String MY_FINAL_STRING = "A String value";

public String[] arrayOfFinalStrings = new String[] {
  MY_FINAL_STRING,
  MY_FINAL_STRING,
  MY_FINAL_STRING,
  MY_FINAL_STRING,
  MY_FINAL_STRING
};
```

It is totaly useless but it what you wanted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Such an operation requires iterating over the elements of the list one way or another.

If you want to avoid typing a loop explicitly, you can use Java 8 Streams.

For example:

```
List<String> newList = origList.stream().map(s->s+"something").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .fill method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

You will need to import java.util.Arrays